# how to get innerHtml of body without an iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I have page with html something like this

```
<body><iframe ></iframe><div id="menu">......</div>.....</body>
```

I want to get the innerHTML of the body but without the iframe? How can i do that in jquery?

Comment: Have you tried yanking the `<iframe>` out of the DOM, grabbing the innerHTML, and then putting the `<iframe>` back?

Comment: cant remove the iframe, it is the part of the ajax history in IE6 and IE7. if i remove it, back button will stop working

Answer (score 4):

Try with [`.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
$(document.body)
    .clone()
    .find('iframe')
        .remove()
    .end()
    .html();
```

Comment: You could also pass `'iframe'` to the call to `remove()`, then you can get rid of `find()` and `end()` calls.

Comment: i have got it to work in Firefox but it does not work in IE6. it returns an empty string in IE6..I am using jquery 1.4.4

Comment: jquery.clone() does not work in IE ..any workaround..I guess I am stuck with my problem

Comment: @kd44 Is your document well-formed HTML? IE6 is very sensitive to malformed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').not('iframe').html();
});
```

that should get everything in the body but the iframe. you'll probably want to store that in a variable or something for reference later

Comment: My [JS Fiddle experiment with that idea](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dyHSU/2/) suggests that [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) doesn't work as you, and *I*, thought it should.

Comment: That won't work. It removes selects all items that match `body` and then removes them if they are also `form` elements.

Comment: I hav tried not , but it does not work, i still get the iframe in the html

Comment: @David Thomas Think of `not` as `filter` inverted and it's much more logical.

Comment: @lonesomeday, yeah, it made sense once I thought it through =)

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to do it

```
var page = $('body').html();
page = $('<div>' + page + '</div>');
var html = $(page).find('iframe').remove().end().html();
```

html variable contains the html without the iframe.

And it works with IE, since jquery.clone() did not work on my page may be because of malformed html as @lonesomeday suggestted